# Roughly cutting Fibre Cables

Tags: networking, cable, fiber

I recently asked a question about [which type of Fibre optic cable to use](https://serverfault.com/questions/119100/fibre-optic-cabling-where-to-start) for my installation. We have now found a cable type and supplier and I'm about to order the cable (OM3, Tight Buffered, 12 Core), however I have a further question:

We are shortly moving in to a new building (still being constructed) and we are about to get a window in which we will be able to run any cabling that we need.

How should I roughly cut the fibre? Can I just use some heavy shears to cut through the cable?

I'm aware that cutting the fibre in this way will damage the ends, but will the damage be limited to the ends, or could the cracks/fractures continue up the length of the cable?

p.s. I have already allowed for several metres of extra cable at each end, and I am going to get a specialist in to terminate the fibres.

Comment: You can't have the contractors that are doing the construction run the cable? Many times they have electricians that are more than capable of properly running fiber and copper. I'd never let them terminate it, but they should be able to run it.

Comment: @MarkM: Hell, yeah, let me get my staple gun and I'll have them orange wires put up real quick like!

Comment: @Dennis Williamson - Most contractors working on office buildings are a little more skilled than your average electricians and are more than capable of properly running copper or fiber.

Comment: @MarkM: "Most" but not all. I've had mixed results. It pays to clearly specify your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the jacket and cut each fiber individually with.  You may find aramid / kevlar in the bundle, so it may be harder than you think to hack away at it with shears.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know if cracks and fractures can travel down the length of the fibre?

Comment: I am sure it could, but it is normal for fiber to be cut as part of the termination process.  I'd be far more worried about it being pulled apart than fractures along the length.